# MySql Retrieve data from same table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I have a table which contains **id**, **name**, **parentId** of Top level Menus & their children like:

```
--------------------------------------
    id    |    name    |    parentId 
--------------------------------------
    1     |    Color   |       0
--------------------------------------
    2     |    Flower  |       0
--------------------------------------
    3     |    Red     |       1
--------------------------------------
    4     |    pink    |       1
--------------------------------------
    5     |    Rose    |       2
--------------------------------------
    6     |    Lily    |       2
--------------------------------------
```

And I want to fetch these record some thing that the resultant array must be like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
    id    |    Pname    |    parentId  |  child    |   childId
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1     |    Color   |       1      |   Red     |    3
---------------------------------------------------------------
    2     |    Color   |       1      |   Pink    |    4
---------------------------------------------------------------
    3     |    Flower  |       2      |   Rose    |    5
---------------------------------------------------------------
    4     |    Flower  |       2      |   Lily    |    6
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

my query was like:

```
SELECT name AS Pname FROM myTbl WHERE id = (SELECT parentId FROM myTbl WHERE parentId = 1 )
```

but **mysql** say #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Could anyone solve it?
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name AS Pname, 
    t2.parentId, t2.name as child, t2.id as childId
FROM myTbl t1
INNER JOIN myTbl t2 on t1.id = t2.parentId
```

Comment: with a little change.SELECT t1.name as 'Parent', t1.id as 'Parent Id', t2.name as 'Child', t2.id as 'Child Id'
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.id = t2.parentId

Answer (score 1):

Problem arises because your subquery is returning more than one row.
Solution is to ensure that the subquery only ever returns one row, or to make sure it doesn't matter if it returns more

But these don't really give you the result that your table suggests you want

```
SELECT name AS Pname 
 FROM myTbl 
WHERE id = ( SELECT DISTINCT parentId 
               FROM myTbl 
              WHERE parentId = 1 
           )
```

OR

```
SELECT name AS Pname 
 FROM myTbl 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT parentId 
                FROM myTbl 
               WHERE parentId = 1 
            )
```